# codeigniter ion auth https redirect infinity loop

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, ssl, https, ion-auth

I have a problem while trying to access a page via https.
Iam using Codeigniter and Ion Auth

This is my config:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http".((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "s" : "")."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (auth|login|pages)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(css|images|js|style)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

The webpage at **https://subdomain.domain.tld/auth/login** has resulted in too many redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to a non-SSL page if the user visits via https which redirects back to https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (auth|login|pages)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

This sends the user to `https` (which will trigger the below Cond)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(css|images|js|style)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

this redirects the user *back* to http which will redirect it back here ad infinitum

try this for your `%{HTTPS} on` condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(css|images|js|style)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

(notice the https in the `RewriteRule`)

Comment: I tried, but Iam still getting same error: To many redirects !!

Comment: Does it happen on other pages too or just the auth/login page?